# Error in function replacement of normal subscribe function declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

### Error in Typescript

- I just want to reuse the function in every successful response from the server in my Angular app instead of declaring it in every block.

The following is the code that causes the error

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
.....
....

addUser(){
 this.http.post<any>(API_ENDPOINT, postData)
            .subscribe( 
               //response when success
               this.registerDone,
               //error
               (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
                }
          );
}
private registerDone(res:any){
        this.clearAuthData();
          .... 
          ....
    }

private clearAuthData() {
        localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
}

}
```

### This is the error

```
core.js:15723 ERROR TypeError: this.clearAuthData is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber.push../src/app/auth/auth.service.ts.AuthService.registerDone [as _next] (auth.service.ts:193)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
```

---

- The ugly workaround is to put everything of registerDone function block into the (res) => { }  OR
- Since I will be reusing **registerDone(res:any)** in other successful response function. It would be nice to use this function in a clean and simple way instead of re-declaring inside every block.

**EDITED**: (res) => {registerDone(res)} Works but not sure whats the difference of using registerDone as an input function since it also accepts one parameters as a function too.

Comment: On post api subscribe you called the function registerDone but there is some syntax error you missed the round braces

Comment: Just replace `this.registerDone` by `() => this.registerDone()`.

Comment: Sorry that would not work ,too.

Comment: First change `this.clearAuthData()` to just `clearAuthData()` in `registerDone` function.
Then change `this.registerDone` to just `registerDone` in subscribe

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet this works but I wonder why registerDone can not be used instead? Actaully I wanted the response as the parameters to be passed downed to so it should be like (res)=> this.registerDone(res)  and private registerDone(res:any)

Comment: Because that's how JavaScript/TypeScript are designed: if you pass a reference to a method, `this` is not bound to the method anymore.

Comment: @NilupulSandeepa Sorry to say that this is required or typescript marked the error as red before compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
export class AuthService {
.....
....

addUser(){
 this.http.post<any>(API_ENDPOINT, postData)
            .subscribe( 
               //response when success
               () => this.registerDone(),
               //error
               (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
                }
          );
}
private registerDone(res:any){
        this.clearAuthData();
          .... 
          ....
    }

private clearAuthData() {
        localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
}

}
```

Non-arrow function bind the `this` keyword to to context where the function will actually be executed i.e *not inside your AuthService* whereas arrow functions will bind `this` to the current instance of AuthService. Check [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881) for more details.